# How to pass display name of table header to partial view

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to pass the table header name to a partial view because I want to display some sorting and search controls for each table header.

This is my partial view:

```
@model string

<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle table-header-button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">@Model</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="/icons/arrow-up.svg" alt="ascending"> Aufsteigend</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="/icons/arrow-down.svg" alt="descending"> Absteigend</a>
        <nav class="dropdown-item navbar navbar-light bg-light">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is how I try to pass my model to the partial view:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <partial name="_TableHeader" for="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)" />                    
                </th>
                ...
            </tr>
        <thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

However, when I do it this way, I always get an error `"Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."` in my table view. I have tried creating a typed model for the partial view, but that yielded the same error.

So how can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `model` attribute of partial tag helper like below

```
 <partial name="_TableHeader" model="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.FirstName)" />
```

For the Partial Tag Helper , you could refer to this link :
https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/partial-tag-helper